# How to set the parent of a gameobject without changing the child's scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to attach a gameObject (childObject) to another gameObject (parentObject) using the SetParent function:
`childObject.transform.SetParent(.transform, true);`

but this approach distorts the child's scale

I have tried dividing the localScale of the childObject by the localScale of the parentObject,
I have tried creating an empty GameObject with a (1,1,1) scale and setting him as the first child of the parentObject and then childObject as the child of the empty Gameobject,

```
var emptyObject = new GameObject();
emptyObject.transform.parent = parentObject.transform;
this.transform.parent = emptyObject.transform;
```

This approach was the closest to working but the childObject still distorts when attaching to a parentObject that was rotated.

I think a lot of problems come from the fact that both the childObject and parentObject both have rotations, but I don't know why rotation would distort the mesh.

Comment: Also similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907064/child-object-transform-position-rotation-scale-incorrect-away-from-origin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809777/divide-a-number-by-a-vector3 .. in general the rotation is an issue yes because it rotates the space the local Scale is applied in